# How to use putImageData() on a rotated canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, gwt

I need to draw rotated image data on a canvas. (This is a GWT project and the context is an instance of `com.google.gwt.canvas.dom.client.Context2d`.)

I am trying to use the following code:

```js
context.rotate(rotation);
context.putImageData(data, x, y);
context.rotate(-rotation);
```

But that code does not draw a rotated image. If I change the code like this:

```js
context.rotate(rotation);
context.fillRect(x, y, 100, 50);
context.rotate(-rotation);
```

then a rotated rectangle will be drawn on the canvas. Is this an API bug, or my fault? What can I do to correct it?

I also tried using `drawImage()` instead of `putImageData()` to test how that method works. It works with rotation fine. But I need to draw `ImageData` that I take from another canvas. Are there any fast methods to translate `ImageData` to `ImageElement`? In what units does `ImageData` return its size?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`putImageData` is not affected by the transformation matrix.

This is by the Spec's orders:

> The current path, transformation matrix, shadow attributes, global alpha, the clipping region, and global composition operator must not affect the getImageData() and putImageData() methods.

What you can do is `putImageData` to an in-memory canvas, and then

```
context.rotate(rotation);
context.drawImage(inMemoryCanvas, x, y)
context.rotate(-rotation);
```

onto your regular canvas.

**NOTE:** from your edit you seem to imply that you might just be drawing from one canvas to another without changing any of the imagedata. If this is the case, definitely just use `drawImage(othercanvas, x, y)` instead of using `getImageData` and `putImageData` if possible. Using `drawImage` is far faster.

Comment: You are right. I do all manipulation in temp canvas and then put that in the correct place on original canvas. Thank for your answer, it helps me a lot.

Comment: How does one get an inMemoryCanvas?

Comment: @NicoWheat `var inMemoryCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');`