# Rotate drawing on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a simple task - I need to draw one rectangle, rotate and copy it and clone its rotated version. I try to do it like so:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//1. rotate canvas
ctx.rotate(-30 * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.rect(10, 60, 80, 40);
ctx.stroke(); 

//2. copy rotated rectangle
var img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 140, 140);

//3. rotate back
ctx.rotate(30 * Math.PI / 180);

//4. draw rotated version of the rectangle
ctx.putImageData(img, 80, 100);
```

The idea is very simple. At first step I draw a rectangle, at the second step I rotate my canvas and do what I think is a snapshot (or create a copy of my rotated rectangle), at the third step I rotate my canvas back (so my rotated rectangle must not be rotated any longer) and at the final step I add a new object to the canvas - the copy of the rotated rectangle. But this is what I get:

[image]

Whereas I expected to get this picture:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the desired result?

Comment: When first rotating you actually are drawing the box. At `//3. rotate back` you rotate, but do nothing with it to draw it to the canvas. https://jsfiddle.net/jr3g9cyk/1/

Comment: Well, you draw rectangles two times. But I want to draw it once and clone it with getImageData.

Comment: It is a strict requirement to use getImageData. The catch is I just simplified my question with two rectangles, but in real world the situation is much worse - there may be some colorized background with different drawings. What I want is rotate this background, create a chunk from it and later draw this chunk at another coordinate.

Comment: If this is not a homework assignment about using `.getImageData` then continue your assignment. Otherwise you need to tell your employer that there are simpler & faster ways of rendering a cloned, rotated rectangle. ;-)

Comment: @markE. 1. It is not. 2. The task is not about rotating rectangles 3. If you read my comment above, you will see, that in real world I need to create a rotated chunk from any background.

Comment: Ok, not homework...then you can probably lose the inefficient `.getImageData` method of copying a canvas. By "chunk" do you mean a clipped section of the canvas? You can more efficiently use `context.clip` or `context.globalCompositeOperation` to fetch a subsection of the canvas.

Comment: Let me explain what I mean by a "rotated chunk". Imagine a canvas with some arbitrary drawings on it. In this case a chunk may be some rectangle at some point and at some angle. And by rectangle I mean here just a region and not a geometric figure drawn on the canvas.

Comment: So, I need to copy some rectangular pieace of the canvas and move it to another point.

Comment: And this rectangular piece of the canvas may be at some angle.

Answer (score 0):

"putImageData is not affected by the transformation matrix"

See here: [putImageData() on rotated canvas work incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638919/putimagedata-on-rotated-canvas-work-incorrect)

Instead, if you want a complex image to be copied into memory, and then repeatedly drawn on the screen at different angles, you might consider using a temporary canvas. This post gives a good example:

[How to rotate the existing content of HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517879/how-to-rotate-the-existing-content-of-html5-canvas)

If you need to create multiple image sprites, and creating multiple canvases won't do, consider drawing your sprite to an appropriately sized temporary canvas, and then convert the contents of the temporary canvas to an image using canvas.toDataUrl

The post gives a nice example:

https://davidwalsh.name/convert-canvas-image

Comment: It would be useful to include some code examples as part of this answer.

Comment: And it would be even more useful, if this code will solve my task =) Though, I think now I can do it myself.